# Медленная работа запроса с двусторонними условиями

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть запрос следующего вида:

```sql
select d.itemcode
from m_items d
left join m_items s on (d.itemcode = s.parentitemcode)
where d.invcode = 10398974 and d.state = 1 --никаких магических констант, просто условия для ограничения выборки
and (s.invdate > '2017-01-01 00:01:00.0000')
and (s.invdate < '2018-12-31 00:00:00.0000')
```

Который работает крайне медленно:

```
Plan
PLAN JOIN (D INDEX (M_ITEMS_INV), S INDEX (M_ITEMS_PARENTITEMCODE_IDX, M_ITEMS_DATE))

------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 16ms
Execute time = 4s 562ms
Avg fetch time = 207,36 ms
Current memory = 10 450 288
Max memory = 10 601 392
Memory buffers = 512
Reads from disk to cache = 451
Writes from cache to disk = 0
Fetches from cache = 155 627
```

При этом запрос с одним граничным условием:

```
select d.itemcode
from m_items d
left join m_items s on (d.itemcode = s.parentitemcode)
where d.invcode = 10398974 and d.state = 1
and (s.invdate > '2017-01-01 00:01:00.0000')
```

работает существенно быстрее:

```
Plan
PLAN JOIN (D INDEX (M_ITEMS_INV), S INDEX (M_ITEMS_PARENTITEMCODE_IDX))

------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 15ms
Execute time = 16ms
Avg fetch time = 0,73 ms
Current memory = 10 448 168
Max memory = 10 601 392
Memory buffers = 512
Reads from disk to cache = 278
Writes from cache to disk = 0
Fetches from cache = 5 147
```

такой же эффект "ускорения" достигается и если вручную исключить индекс `M_ITEMS_DATE` например так:

```
select d.itemcode
from m_items d
left join m_items s on (d.itemcode = s.parentitemcode)
where d.invcode = 10398974 and d.state = 1 --никаких магических констант, просто условия для ограничения выборки
and (s.invdate+0 > '2017-01-01 00:01:00.0000')
and (s.invdate < '2018-12-31 00:00:00.0000')
```

А теперь вопросы:

1. Почему запрос с одним условием не использует индекс `M_ITEMS_DATE`, в то время как запрос с двумя ограничениями использует?
2. Почему без индекса работает быстрее? (Впрочем я догадываюсь, почему: после `JOIN` остается довольно мало записей и их быстрее перебрать `NATURAL`)

Comment: попробуйте добавить преобразование '2017-01-01 00:01:00.0000' к дате. индекс может отваливаться если invdate пытается преобразовать в строку.

Comment: 1. Поппробуйте переставить условия при and местами. 2. Вам действительно нужен left join? Возможно ускорит перенести условия чисто с s в `inner join` s. 3. Поставьте between.

Comment: @Okdel нет, оптимизатор конечно не 7 пядей во лбу, но догадывается, что надо константу кастить к типу столбца, а не столбец.

Comment: @nick_n_a Наличие условий по правой таблице вырождает LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN. Так что нужен или не нужен - уже не обсуждается, заменить безусловно. А перемещение условий или замена на BETWEEN ничего не даст - это будут просто разные формы одного и того же запроса.

Comment: @nick_n_a Перестановка не помогает, план остается тот же. `between` - так же не меняет ситуацию. В оригинальном запросе нужен `left join`, здесь приведен эрзац, самый сок. Проверил - внутреннее объединение так же не решает проблему.

Comment: Перестановка условий может поменять время выполнения (может так же и не поменять). between - чисто красота.

Comment: Коллеги! приведенный запрос - это "образец" на котором наблюдаются эффекты. Меня больше всего волнует первый вопрос - почему не используется индекс когда есть условие на одну границу?

Comment: @AlexanderSashurin *почему не используется индекс когда есть условие на одну границу?* Вероятно, оптимизатор считает, что селективность недостаточно высока для того, чтобы индекс был эффективен по сравнению со сканом таблицы. Если это не так, попробуйте пересчитать статистику.

Comment: @Akina ok, тогда почему этот же индекс начинает использоваться, когда появляется 2 условия? В чем логика?

Comment: Индекс при этом используется для прямого скана на сортированном наборе. Т.е. при двух сравнениях индекс используется так, как таблица при одном. PS. Вот если бы Firebird знал про RTree...

Comment: @Akina Какие нибудь возможности для тюнинга этого индекса есть? А если перейти на 3 версию Firebird?

Comment: Да нет у него никаких средств управления индексами... можете попробовать эмулировать INTERSECT через INNER JOIN двух подзапросов (с ограничением сверху и снизу соответственно) - но мне сомнительно, что будет эффект.

Comment: @Akina эффект есть, я до этого еще в пятницу дошел. Другое дело, что это более накладно чем `s.invdate+0 > some_const`, тогда да, оптимизатор прекращает использовать индекс и все летает

Comment: @alexander-sashurin тут вы ошибаетесь, оптимизатор может вытворять весьма своеобразные преобразования. Все зависит от того с какого края он начнет выполнять запрос, а это уже зависит от собранной статистики. 
В данном же случае, мне кажется, что оптимизатор делает выборки по таблицам отдельно, а затем их джойнит. Видимо выборка по таблице s возвращает слишком большой объем данных. Проверить это вы можете, банально оставив работу с таблицей s. Выборка теоретически должна вернуть около 155 627 записей, в то время как выборка без дат возвращает около 5 147 записей.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, с двумя индексами он сначала по дате отбирает большой массив данных, что занимает много времени, а потом уже из него маленький кусок по коду родителя.

Могу сказать, что такая работа оптимизатора тянется с самых ранних версий Interbase еще (в 4-й версии еще так было, более ранних я не видел).

Странно только, что left join вас от второго индекса не спас.

Какая у вас версия Firebird если не секрет?